# Why does this division give a "Numeric overflow in expression" warning?

Tags: android-studio

In an android source file in Android Studio 2.3.3 I get a warning in the second statement "Numeric overflow in expression"

```
        float f1 = (float) (-Math.PI / 3.0); // OK
        float f2 = (float) (-Math.PI / 7.0); // Warning
```

Why would that be? Or is this just an inspection error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not java developer, but I think that when dividing by 7 the result goes out of float type bounds. So I think you really should use double type instead of float and see if the problem persists.

As noted in this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (and generally) and said roughly double have "doubled capacity" of float.

Comment: Both Math.PI and 7.0 are doubles. Only the result is cast to a float

Comment: then, it's logical that overflow happens, since result `double / double` occupies more space in memory than `float`, so please try `double f2 = (float) (-Math.PI / 7.0);`. In the first case, maybe LSBs are zeros and conversion happens without any data loss and zeros are thrown away?!